# Finding a way to efficiently perform calculation for certain column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to look at a specific column of a Pandas DataFrame and trying to do the following:

```
col0 col1   col2
int0 float0 str0
int1 float1 str0
int2 float2 str1
```

I am trying to just iterate over the DataFrame row by row on that column, but this doesn't seem efficient.. Lambdas are an option, but I'm not sure if there is something like a "list comprehension" for DataFrame columns (which are Pandas Series, as far as I understand).

If, let's say, the DataFrame is defined as df, then I want to do something such as:

```py
for row in df:
    if df['col2'] == str0:
        # do some calculation for all str0 types
    elif df['col2'] == str1:
        # do another calculation for all str1 types
    else:
        # do another calculation for all other types (which are actually str2 types implied by the if-elif-else statement)
```

I am trying to repeat this in order to get a separate NumPy matrix that will create a NumPy row corresponding to the respective row of the DataFrame. By checking the condition for "col2", a separate calculation will be performed depending on its value, and the row for the respective NumPy array will be generated.

Please let me know if there is an efficient way (both in terms of canonical, Pythonic coding as well as time and memory efficiency)! All help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many different string value do you have ? There are way more efficient way to do it than a for loop.  + What are the calculation you are doing ? Are you applying a value in a new column ?

Comment: The other idea I had was using lambdas to apply different calculations for each string value. For this case, I only have 3 string values, so it would be much better to apply a calculation efficiently; however, scalable ideas would also be very helpful (say, if there were 1000s of possible values for the strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a `np.select` problem

```
condition = [df['col2'] == str0, df['col2'] == str1...]
Target = [function1 , function2...]

df['NewCol'] = np.select(condition , Target , default = np.nan )
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing from a maintenance prospective would be to create a function such as:

```
def fn(x):
    if x < 5:
        return x * 2
    else:
        return x * 3
```

And then apply it to your column:

```
df["col2"].apply(fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by separating out the rows corresponding to each value of the `col2` column.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col0=[0,1,2], col1=[3.0, 4.0, 5.0], col2=['str0', 'str0', 'str1']))
>>> col2_elm_to_df = {col2_elm: group_df for col2_elm, group_df in df.groupby('col2')}
>>> col2_elm_to_df
{
    'str0':          col0  col1  col2
               0     0     3.0   str0
               1     1     4.0   str0, 

    'str1':          col0  col1  col2
               2     2     5.0   str1
}
```